# How to efficiently replace words in a string with a random replacement words?

Tags: string, go, substring

I need to create function that replaces placeholders for words in a string with predefined unique replacements. Newly generated string should not contain repetitive replacement words and they should be picked randomly. Assume that replacement array contains enough words.
Example:

```
replacement := []string{"Cat", "Dog"}
s := "{replacement} text {replacement}"
result := "Cat text Dog"
```

I was thinking about doing something like this:

1. While words contain replacement placeholders pick a random unique replacement word and replace it with a picked word.
2. Continue the above until all replacements placeholders are replaced with a replacement.

Comment: Did you consider Golang templates ? https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard package `regexp` has a `*Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc` is just for this:

From doc:

> ReplaceAllStringFunc returns a copy of src in which all matches of the Regexp have been replaced by the return value of function repl applied to the matched substring. The replacement returned by repl is substituted directly, without using Expand.

To replace it without repetitive replacement, you can use `rand.Shuffle` to shuffle `replacement` and then use content of it one by one.

For example:

```
rand.Shuffle(len(rep), reflect.Swapper(rep))
var err error
res := pattern.ReplaceAllStringFunc(s, func(x string) string {
    if len(rep) == 0 {
        err = errors.New("Not enough replacements for string.")
        return "<not enough replacement>"
    }
    s, rep = rep[0], rep[1:]
    return s
})
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_FuFqT5rHJc

Comment: it is more appropriate to shuffle once upfront. It prevents value duplication and avoids some more [locks](https://tip.golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go?#L293) in [rand.Intn](https://tip.golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go?#L327). https://play.golang.org/p/y02T_v68FZh

Comment: @mh-cbon you are right, I missed that part in question.